# Real time peak width plotting in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I would like to plot, in real time, the peak width of my signal. I am having 
trouble using my current approach. I have a user defined threshold value, and 
when the value of my signal goes above this value, I would like to start a 
timer. Then when the signal goes below the threshold, I would like to stop that timer and plot that value before resetting the timer. I am having trouble with how I can use the various timing functions to do this. I am working on using the select function to output the timestamp if the signal is above the threshold. That might not be the right thing to do though. Possibly plotting the sum of these values while the signal is above threshold and subtracting the sum from itself while it is below will give me peak widths values in real time.

Is this a potential approach for measuring peak width? Do you have any 
recommendation on how I can utilize timing functions to perform a peak width 
measurement based on user defined threshold. Are there any better options using the data format I have?
Here is my block diagram, and then an image of my signal.

LabVIEW image:

[image: LabVIEW image]

Signal:

[image: Signal]

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are acquiring or generating your signal - preferably as a [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/)

Comment: OK, it's useful to see what the signal looks like, but can we have one showing just the block diagram please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of measuring time using the timing functions in LabVIEW is to use the Get Date/Time in Seconds or Tick Count function to grab the time at the start of a process, and then call it again later, subtracting your old value from it to see how much time has passed. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a some vi's in the `Signal Processing - Signal Operation` palette that might help you:  `Peak Detector` and `Threshold Detector`.
The input and output is in samples, so you need to convert to your prefered time unit.

You might also get some useful info from here: http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/3770/en/